# Proving that something is a diagonal?

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose that D is a diagonal matrix with entries λ1, . . . , λn and
that S is an invertible matrix. Suppose that each column of S is a multiple of a standard basis vector (i.e. an $~e_i$). Prove that $S^{−1}DS$ is diagonal.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Note that each column of $S$ is an eigenvector of $D$.